# How to stream result from grpc-server and how to return result from goroutines grpc server-stream to pass result to api

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I have an api created via golang which return the result of

```
{
   id : drone4
   item_parameter : {
       altitude : 20,
       longitude : 10.20
      latitude : 24.5
}
```

as a json result, but in the code it uses
go routines which call the go func() to process 
the result from grpc-server golang

like this

```
go func() {
        fmt.Print("start getPosition loop")
        for {
            msg, err := stream.Recv() // msg UAVPosition
            if err == io.EOF {
                // read done.
                fmt.Print("start getPosition loop closed")
                close(position)
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to receive getPosition : %v", err)
                close(position)
                return
            }
            log.Printf("Position point[%s](%f, %f, %f)", uavID.Aircraft, msg.Latitude, msg.Longitude, msg.Altitude)

            itemParameter := models.ItemParameter{
                Latitude:  msg.Latitude,
                Longitude: msg.Longitude,
                Altitude:  msg.Altitude,
            }

            position <- models.DronePosition{
                Name:          uavID.Aircraft,
                ItemParameter: itemParameter,
            }
        }
    }()
```

I need to get the positon value which is i used this channel

```
position := make(chan models.DronePosition)
```

if any chance how can I get this result to stream to the ui using go?
any suggestion how to work this streaming way in ui?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly -> this is server grpc endpoint and your problem is how to send `models.DronePosition` back to the client. If so, then you have bidirectional streaming and you can solve this problem as:

```
dronePosition := models.DronePosition{
                Name:          uavID.Aircraft,
                ItemParameter: itemParameter,
            }
position <- dronePosition
err = stream.Send(&dronePosition)
```

And on the client there should be the corresponding update to support bidirectional data streaming

Comment: this is the golang grpc goroutines and how can I write this code?

currently I have this as 

```
dronePos := <-position

maybe ill add 

err = stream.Send(&dronePosition)

and stream.CloseSend()
```

Please correct me

where should i add this result?

Comment: Well, I see that you have here client streaming ( by calling `stream.Recv()` in a cycle. I don't know how your `.proto` file looks like, but you need for your task change it in a way that it supports bidirectional data streaming, regenerate service code (if it was not bidirectional) and add logic for returning answer via `err = stream.Send(&dronePosition)`

Comment: This is my current code I changed i
```
itemParameter := models.ItemParameter{
    Latitude:  msg.Latitude,
    Longitude: msg.Longitude,
    Altitude:  msg.Altitude,
   }

   dronePosition := models.DronePosition{
    Name:          uavID.Aircraft,
    ItemParameter: itemParameter,
   }

   position <- dronePosition
```
but the problem is how can I pass to my api? this is written in golang and also there is grpc server function that sends a message so my job is to return the response to api stream simultaneously

Comment: maube I don't understand your initial question. Do you want to pass it immediately? Then just turn it back in bidirectional way. If you need to pass it to another endpoint (some integration) -> then just put it for a while into DB

Comment: what really happen my api must accept multiple request 

```
stream API must have a compatible client from the UI.
and multi client/object. meaning, it supports multiple stream from your API to multiple drone on the map

single connection but supports multiple drone
```
which if i use get request this would be difficult to achieve also the streaming is happening in the grpc and also the api should stream as well (golang) am finding a way how to handle this and also as I ask a while a go, i searched last week on how to get result from the go routines which is difficult.

Comment: I suggest you to read about grpc. For example, there is a good example of bidirectional grpc calling: https://rakyll.org/grpc-streaming/